# Finding the row in mysql database that a submit button corresponds to

Tags: php, mysql, button, submit

I have multiple submit buttons on the same page with the same name and value. Right now I'm not sure how to distinguish between two of them using php (and I want to know what I could use to do that). I've read in some places that this can be done by making each button have a different value but since each one has almost the same functionality (which I will describe soon) I'd prefer they had the same value (but if this is my last resort then I'll do it).
Each button is supposed to increment a value in a mysql database. For example:
submit1 will increment the score of the row who's primary id is 1.
Right now I have no idea how to do this and I'm pretty sure I'm making a mistake here since I couldn't find anyone using a method similar to mine to perform the operation I'm trying to do. If you could tell me what I should be doing then that would be great :)

Comment: you need to define those buttons with different name, else you have no chance of detecting which one is pressed with php. except you are willing to go through the trouble of setting another field a different value once a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I would give each button a different name and use the isset cmd in php.

```
if (isset($_POST['buttonname'])) {
    //do something
    $myval = $myval + $_POST['buttonname'];
}
```